# Using BuildConfig.FLAVOR with android databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, buildconfig

I have used below code in my layout file to change two different view visibility according to flavor type of the application. I haven't seen any problems with debug build but i believe there is an issue with release build because I have been reported that both views are visible on the test release. Any idea why would this happen?

```
                    <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/configuration_main_network_switch"
                        style="@style/networkSelector"
                        android:visibility="@{BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(`xxxx`) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                        android:text="@{configurationMainNetworkSwitch.checked ? @string/network_configuration_main_wifi_enabled_button : @string/network_configuration_main_wifi_disabled_button}" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/configuration_main_network_switch_gone"
                        style="@style/networkSelector"
                        android:visibility="@{BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(`xxxx`) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                        android:text="@string/network_configuration_main_wifi_enabled_button"/>
```

Comment: I would instead suggests to make new directories specific to your flavors and then put the same layout file in res directory inside both of them specific to your logic. *(One not having both these views while another having them)*

Comment: Or try to call `setVisibility` directly. Have you tried to use getter instead of calling`BuildConfig` directly in xml?

Comment: @user1209216 I tried that, will see if it works or not. Like i said, this is only on release build.

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede I will try that next.

Comment: Do you use R8 or ProGuard? If so, try to disable it

Answer (score 0):

Import the required data-types first:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.acme.BuildConfig"/>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

Then they can be referenced in data-binding statements:

```
android:visibility="@{ BuildConfig.DEBUG ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }"
```

I can also get the product flavor:

```
android:text="@{ BuildConfig.FLAVOR }"
```

Maybe the string being compared to doesn't match?